# Laravel Sail Mysql 8.0 problem on existing project

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker, laravel-sail

I've an already created project and I wanted to start using laravel sail for my local development but when I start the containers with `sail up --build` I have and error in the mysql container with the following complete output:

```
merkat-db       | 2021-01-14T16:34:34.729905Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
redis_1         | 1:M 14 Jan 2021 16:34:34.340 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
redis_1         | 1:M 14 Jan 2021 16:34:34.340 # Server initialized
redis_1         | 1:M 14 Jan 2021 16:34:34.340 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
redis_1         | 1:M 14 Jan 2021 16:34:34.340 * Loading RDB produced by version 6.0.10
redis_1         | 1:M 14 Jan 2021 16:34:34.340 * RDB age 1236 seconds
redis_1         | 1:M 14 Jan 2021 16:34:34.340 * RDB memory usage when created 0.77 Mb
redis_1         | 1:M 14 Jan 2021 16:34:34.340 * DB loaded from disk: 0.000 seconds
redis_1         | 1:M 14 Jan 2021 16:34:34.340 * Ready to accept connections
merkat-db       | 2021-01-14T16:34:34.891168Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
merkat-app      | 2021-01-14 16:34:34,914 CRIT Supervisor is running as root.  Privileges were not dropped because no user is specified in the config file.  If you intend to run as root, you can set user=root in the config file to avoid this message.
merkat-app      | 2021-01-14 16:34:34,914 INFO Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf" during parsing
merkat-app      | 2021-01-14 16:34:34,918 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
merkat-app      | 2021-01-14 16:34:34,918 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
merkat-app      | 2021-01-14 16:34:34,919 INFO supervisord started with pid 16
merkat-db       | 2021-01-14T16:34:34.974741Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
merkat-db       | 2021-01-14T16:34:35.071102Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013595] [Server] Failed to initialize TLS for channel: mysql_main. See below for the description of exact issue.
merkat-db       | 2021-01-14T16:34:35.071429Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010069] [Server] Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths failed
merkat-db       | 2021-01-14T16:34:35.072494Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010285] [Server] Failure to parse RSA private key (file exists): /var/lib/mysql//private_key.pem: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line
merkat-db       | 2021-01-14T16:34:35.073336Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
merkat-app      | 2021-01-14 16:34:35,921 INFO spawned: 'php' with pid 18
merkat-app      | Starting Laravel development server: http://0.0.0.0:80
merkat-db       | 2021-01-14T16:34:36.494723Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.22)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
merkat-app      | [Thu Jan 14 16:34:36 2021] PHP 8.0.1 Development Server (http://0.0.0.0:80) started
merkat-db exited with code 1
```

The error is on this line

```
merkat-db       | 2021-01-14T16:34:35.071429Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010069] [Server] Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths failed
merkat-db       | 2021-01-14T16:34:35.072494Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010285] [Server] Failure to parse RSA private key (file exists): /var/lib/mysql//private_key.pem: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line
```

Steps I've already made to try to resolve this:

- Create a new private_key.pem
- Change the mysql version
- Delete all the images from docker with  `docker system prune -a`

Nothing worked.

I can connect to MySQL if I create a new project, I just can't use it on already created projects

Comment: Does your `private_key.pem` start with `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`?

Comment: Hello, yes it does

Answer (score 23):

I resolved this by doing the following command:

```
docker-compose down --volumes
```

And then:

```
sail up --build
```

I think the container was corrupted for some reason

Comment: This worked to me and my issue was 'root'  user and password ,  change it  try with above commands.It should work

Comment: @SampathGunasekara this was it, thanks

Comment: Should note that this *removes* the docker volumes and you will lose all corresponding data

Answer (score 2):

If you run the commands below and don't work

```
docker-compose down --volumes
 
sail up --build
```

Try to change the .env DB_USERNAME, probably it is **root** and will not work for root username.